# realmswift Getting realm/util/features.h not found when compiling

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an ios app written in swift, and i am using RealmSwift to save my data, before upgrading to the latest release the app was running fine, but after upgrading to realmswift 0.97 It started getting this issue every time i try to run the app

```
> Pods/Realm/include/realm/string_data.hpp:33:10:
> 'realm/util/features.h' file not found

Pods/Realm/Realm/ObjectStore/object_schema.cpp:19:10: In file included from Pods/Realm/Realm/ObjectStore/object_schema.cpp:19:

Pods/Realm/include/realm/object_schema.hpp:22:10: In file included from Pods/Realm/include/realm/object_schema.hpp:22:
```

Comment: This is a verbatim copy of https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3141 which was filed at the same time. For future reference, the Realm team monitors both GitHub issues and StackOverflow, so there's no need to cross-post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the realm issues log i found a related issue, the issue is related to cocoapod 1.0 beta.

the solution is to use the stable release of cocoapod 0.39.

for more details please read this issue log

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3052

Answer (score 5):

Are you using a release candidate of CocoaPods 1.0 by any chance? If so, please note that Realm only supports the latest stable version of CocoaPods (0.39.0) and that Realm is tracking adding support for CocoaPods 1.0 in [#3052](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3052).

If you're already using CocoaPods 0.39.0, you can reset your pods installation by running the following commands, which should reinstall Realm successfully:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
pod install
```

If this still doesn't help, please report back providing more information following Realm's [guidelines](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#filing-issues).

Answer (score 0):

I Just got same error yesterday, i was using Cocoapod 1.2.1 (Newest).
And i notice that current version of Realm is 0.96.2.
So i change to 2.7.0 (Newest)

```
pod 'RealmSwift' , '~> 2.7.0'
```

Hope this help.